# JQuery - Remove class to make menu overlay fade back out

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menu like this

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The menu is hidden and when a hamburger icon is clicked it appears as an overlay. I'd like to remove class 'open' from nav when any one of the links is clicked.

I tried this-

```
<script>    
    $('nav.overlay-menu ul li a').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').removeClass(".open"); });
</script>
```

but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `.` in the class name. removeClass knows it's a class (or at least assumes it's a class).

`$('nav.overlay-menu ul li a').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').removeClass("open"); });`

```js
$('nav.overlay-menu ul li a').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').removeClass("open");
});

$('#burger').on('click', function() {
  $('#overlay').addClass('open');
  });
```

```css
.open { background: #ffa; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="burger">click</div>
```

Seems to work fine in the snippet above.

Comment: Thanks! It still does not remove the class!?

Comment: I added the script inside my page before loading jQuery! Thanks!

Comment: I edited to add a snippet.. seems to work just fine here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set all chain of children to find element. You can do something like this:

```js
    $('.overlay-menu a')
```

and find and close menu using this example

```js
    $('.overlay-menu a').on('click', function(){
       $('#overlay').removeClass('open');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```